# Which type of PHP Object pattern use case it is?

Tags: php, oop

Consider the following code:

```
UM()->Activity_API()->api()->get_author( $id )
```

I am confused with what is `UM()` here. Is it a class? If yes then why it is referred with round brackets, and how `Activity_API()` method is further refereed to `api()` method and then `get_author()` method?

Comment: If `UM` is a class, it should be `new UM()`.

Comment: This is called Fluent Interface and method chaining. you can read more about it here https://dev.to/mofiqul/fluent-interface-and-method-chaining-in-php-and-javascript-251c

Comment: `x()->y()->z()` just means to call the `y()` method on the value returned by `x()`, and the `z()` method on the value returned by `y()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AzazKhan and Barmar . Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, `UM` is not a class, but a function that returns an object that has a public `Activity_API()` method.

E.g.

```
class Foo {
    public function Activity_API() 
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}

function UM(): Foo {
    return new Foo();
}

UM()->Activity_API();
```

This one specifically is documented [here](https://ultimatemember.com/php-docs/files/includes.class-init.html). The function `UM()` returns an instance of `\UM`, a class of the same name.

This kind of approach is simply used to have a more concise and explicit builder. You could do exactly the same by doing:

```
(new \UM())->Activity_API()->api()->get_author( $id )
```

Each of the methods in the chain return another object. In this case another instance of [`\UM`](https://ultimatemember.com/php-docs/classes/UM.html).

Since each method in the chain returns another object, you can call any public method or access any public property of the returned object without creating any intermediate variable.

This is called a "[Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)":

> In software engineering, a fluent interface is an object-oriented API whose design relies extensively on method chaining. Its goal is to increase code legibility by creating a domain-specific language. The term was coined in 2005 by Eric Evans and Martin Fowler.

Comment: Thank you so much. Really a detailed answer, clearly understood now. Much Appreciated. :-)